# Ubuntu down load a package and all of its dependencies without installing them

Tags: ubuntu, download, package

I need to download a package and all of its dependencies without installing any of them.

I'm looking for a command like `apt-get -R --download-only install package-name`

Or any solution that would produce the same result.

Based on my research I could not find a solution that produces this and I have tried combining commands to produce something similar which doesn't work every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [camicri](https://launchpad.net/camicricube) to download a package with all of its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/, search for your package there and it will give you the option to download it or the url to download the package.  Hope this helps.